# Is there a way to inspect the css of a pdf file when it is in print template in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I want to debug some css that is breaking on my pdf template, but not able to inspect the styles in css. On inspect element we get the styles only for the text and elements on chrome, we don't get the styles of pdf on inspect. It just reflects as an iframe node in the DOM Tree for PDF.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ? I'm looking for to over css PDF Template's CSS - is that possible ?

Answer (score -2):

See if you want to just have a look on the inspection of a pdf file from a normal website then go to `chrome` -> open the pdf `(ctrl + p)` -> then press `(f11) for inspection` -> then go on the`most right end`on the tab where `console` and `sources` are -> you will find `three dots` -> click them -> you will have three options there  click `(open the dock in a separate windows)`  and then you will get the inspection and the source code and everything